# Regex in Django for URL with % or &

Tags: python, regex, django

I have a URL that is either going to be `united-states/boulder-21781/tool-&-anchor/mulligan-21/`. Assuming the best strategy is to encode the &, the url changes to `united-states/boulder-21781/tool-%26-anchor/mulligan-21/`

I'm trying to write a url conf that will accept this, but the regex I'm using isn't working. I have:

```
    url(r'^%(regex)s/%(regex)s-(\d+)/%(regex)s/%(regex)s-(\d+)/$' % {'regex'= '(?i)([\.\-\_\w]+)'}, 'view_tip_page', name='tip_page'),
```

What do I add to capture the %?  or should i just include the &?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well currently there is no way for you to match `%` or `&` in your regex.  Depending on whether it is encoded or not, you will need to add one or the other to the character class in your regex, and it should match.

I might change it to something like the following:

```
r'(?i)^%(regex)s/%(regex)s-(\d+)/%(regex)s/%(regex)s-(\d+)/$' % {'regex': r'([-.%\w]+)'}
```

And proof that it works:

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'(?i)^%(regex)s/%(regex)s-(\d+)/%(regex)s/%(regex)s-(\d+)/$' % {'regex': r'([-.%\w]+)'})
>>> s = 'united-states/boulder-21781/tool-%26-anchor/mulligan-21/'
>>> match = pattern.match(s)
>>> match.groups()
('united-states', 'boulder', '21781', 'tool-%26-anchor', 'mulligan', '21')
```

A few comments on your regex:

The `(?i)` isn't really doing anything, since you are using `\w` which will already match both upper and lowercase.  If you do want to use `(?i)` I would move it out of the replacement string and into the format string (`'(?i)...' % {'regex': '...'}` instead of `'...' % {'regex': '(?i)...'}`), since otherwise it will show up multipe times.

Note that character class was changed from `[\.\-\_\w]` to `[-.%\w]`, this is because underscores are included in `\w`, you don't need to escape the hyphen if it comes at the beginning of the character class, and you don't need to escape the `.` inside of character classes.

Also, `\w` does match digits so technically to match something like 'boulder-21781' you could just use `%(regex)s` instead of `%(regex)s-(\d+)`, but I didn't want to change that in case it was intentionally adding some additional verification of the format.

Answer (score 1):

My first recommendation would be to not do it. As you yourself are demonstrating, not everybody knows that a `&` is a perfectly valid character in a URI before the first `?`, and you are bound to get into trouble. It also looks ugly, is harder to type, and more jarring than, say, `and`, or even just `n`. Having said that, if you *really* want it in there, just put it in there in the character class.

Not related to your question, the way you're building that regex is weird; you're not capturing any of the bits of the path for use by the view. You're also including the `(?i)` global modifier four times, and specifying `_` which is already part of `\w`. I dunno, I'd expect something like

```
r'(?i)(?P<country>[.\w-]+)/(?P<city>[.\w-]+)-(?P<cityno>[\d+])/...etc...
```

but maybe I'm missing something.